# Church–Turing thesis for higher order functions

Tags: lo.logic, computability-theory

The Church–Turing thesis states that, simply speaking, any reasonable definition of "effectively computable functions" $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb N$ agrees with the definition using Turing machines. Is there a version that applies to higher order functions, such as $(\mathbb N \to \mathbb N) \to \mathbb N$?

A few difficulties I could think of:

- The domain of these functions is unclear. Should it be all functions, or computable functions only? Do we have a separate Church–Turing thesis for each?
- If there are indeed inequivalent definitions, can we fully classify them?

Perhaps a more operable question is to compare the realizability topos $\textsf{Rz}(A)$ for different reasonable partial combinatory algebras $A$, where $(\mathbb N \to \mathbb N) \to\mathbb N$ would be unambiguously defined. But now they are in different categories so how can we compare them?

Comment: The papers “4-Quantifier Completeness: A Banach-Mazur Functional not Uniformly Partial Recursive” by Richard Friedberg, *Bull. Acad. Pol. Sci.* **6** (1958) 1–5 should be relevant to the question (it is unfindable online, but [see this account](https://doi.org/10.2307/2964575)). For a more recent result on the reals, see: [“A Banach–Mazur computable but not Markov computable function on the computable real numbers” by Peter Hertling, *Ann. Pure Appl. Logic* **132** (2005) 227–246](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.apal.2004.08.001).

Comment: Re my previous comment: this is about functions $(\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}) \to (\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N})$ (in Friedberg's paper) or $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ (in Hertling's paper), where two different notions of computability appear as fairly standard: Banach-Mazur computability and Kleene-Markov(?) computability. See [this page](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Banach-Mazur_functional) for some background, as well as the answers to [this other question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/21947/17064).

Comment: Then [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/computable+analysis) has a page on  the concepts mentioned by Gro-Tsen. But in the case of functions on $\mathbb{R}$, there is also a (different) notion of computability due to [Blum, Shub, and Smale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blum%E2%80%93Shub%E2%80%93Smale_machine).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer to the question you ask can be found in John Longley's paper [On the ubiquity of certain total type structures](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0960129507006251) ([PDF](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/jrl/Research/ubiquity-full.pdf) available here). Briefly, one can define the higher-type functionals by $N_0 = \mathbb{N}$ and $N_{k+1} = N_k \to \mathbb{N}$. Depending on the setting in which the definition is interpreted (domains, realizability models, a programming language such as PCF), we get various hierarchies of functionals.

John Longley shows and explains that there are *three* "naturally occurring" such hierarchies: the hereditarily effective one, the continuous one, and the effective continuous one. It's a wonderful and very deep paper. I cannot begin to explain why this is the case, but John does an excellent job in the introduction.

Comment: Does Longley's “effective” hierarchy coincide with the one defined in chapters VI & VII of [Hinman's classic book *Recursion-Theoretic Hierarchies* (Springer Persp. Math. Logic 1978)](https://projecteuclid.org/eBooks/perspectives-in-logic/Recursion-Theoretic-Hierarchies/toc/pl/1235415519) (freely available at this link)? He doesn't cite it, so I wonder if there's a catch.

Comment: There are many books, why do you expect him to cite this particular one? Two chapters is kind of a wide target. Can you be more specific about which definition you're asking about? Where in the book is there a hierarchy of functionals?

Comment: I believe (maybe wrongly) that Hinman's book, as well as Sacks's *Higher Recursion Theory* is standard. But mostly I'm trying to ascertain that there isn't a case of two different schools of mathematics (e.g., the “set-theoretic school” and the “realizability-theoretic school” — I'm just guessing) that would have subtly different definitions about computability in higher types. E.g., does everyone agree that subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ recursive in $E:\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}\to\mathbb{N}$ taking $α$ to $0$ when $∃m.α(m)=0$ and $1$ otherwise are the same as lightface $Δ^1_1$? \[contd.\]

Comment: \[contd.\] Anyway, the relevant definitions in Hinman's book are: definitions VI.1.1 on page 260 (recursion in a type-2 functional), VI.7.1 on page 335 (recursiveness of type-3 functionals), VII.1.1 on page 344 (recursion in a type-3 functional) and VII.4.1 on page 364 (recursion in higher types, which Hinman claims presents nothing newsworthy after type 4). (They also refer to definition II.2.1 on page 39 for ordinary recursion.) And the “test” theorem about $Δ^1_1$ I just cited is theorem VI.1.8 on page 267.

Comment: But don't go through too much trouble reading them for my sake! If you're fairly confident that there aren't competing or subtly different definitions of computability in higher types beyond the three naturally occurring ones Longley mentions, that's good enough. (I'll try to digest Longley's paper and see if I can persuade myself that Hinman's definitions match up.)

Comment: I think there's a misundertanding about the word "higher". Hinman's book is about computability schemata which clearly exceed the power of Turing machines, and also seem to pay little or no attention to continuity. John's paper is about actually computable and actually continuous functionals, so that's different.

Comment: A modern and readable account (not wraught with 1970's trends of obfuscating texts in logic) is Longley and Normann's [Higher-Order Computability](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-662-47992-6). It contains John's paper and much more, including computability of the kind that Hinman is writing about.

Comment: Hinman's emphasis is about computability beyond Turing machines (and the result about $Δ^1_1$ that I mentioned is certainly of that sort), but I don't think the definitions themselves imply this: e.g., if you evaluate a functional $F\colon \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ that is computable in Hinman's sense on an element of $α\colon \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ that is Turing-computable, you get a function $k\mapsto F(α,k)\colon \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ that is also Turing-computable. Or am I missing something obvious? Maybe I can open another question about this.

Comment: (Amusingly, Hinman's *Recursion-Theoretic Hierachies* book is referenced (as item \[117\]) in the bibliography of Longley and Normann's 2015 book *Higher-Order Computability*, but the reference doesn't appear to be cited anywhere: it seems to be an orphan reference. I don't know what to conclude from this.)

Comment: Update: after glancing through Longley and Normann's book, I'm convinced that the definition that Hinman's book uses of computability in higher types is the same as what Longley and Normann (and Sam Sanders's other answer) call “Kleene's S1–S9”, a terminology I was unaware of.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen As far as I know, Kleene's S1-S9 schemes (and the 'ready' generalisations to partial objects) yield the most general notion of computability.  For the record, "infinite time Turing machines" compute things that are "hard to compute" from the pov of S1-S9, like finite sub-covers of uncountable coverings of the unit interval.

Answer (score 9):

Dag Normann (and myself) have written in many places that:

*there is no Church-Turing thesis for computability of (even just) type 2 objects*.

As noted here by others, John Longley has explored this theoretical question in some detail.  Dag and I can offer some practical experience as follows.

*In general, if $X, Y$ are natural type 2 objects and $X$ computes $Y$ in the sense of Kleene's S1-S9, then $X$ generally also computes $Y$ via some term of Goedel's $T$ of relatively low complexity.*

There are however exceptions and the aforementioned terms of Goedel's $T$ can be complicated and ad hoc.

I would conclude from the above that S1-S9 is among the most general notions of computability for type 2 objects, which is interesting for negative results.  For positive results, S1-S9 often seems overly general, with known exceptions.  This constitutes evidence for the absence of a Church-Turing-thesis.

Finally, there is an elegant *lambda calculus plus fixed point operators* formulation of S1-S9 [here](https://doi.org/10.1093/logcom/exac075).  In this framework, one can readily define sub-notions of S1-S9-computability (whereas S1-S9 is rather monolithic due to S9).  This again constitutes evidence for the absence of a Church-Turing-thesis.

Comment: Using “in general” to mean “for the most part” can be dangerous in math.